# How do possible future court cases affect a bankruptcy application or judgement?

Tags: bankruptcy

Asking with regard to the USA.

I have court cases I have been considering filing, suing specific people or organizations for damages. I've been advised that I don't have a lot of ground to sue and would probably not be successful. This is not a simple issue like a debt or something similar.

Would I need to declare every possible entity I think I could have a claim on when filing for bankruptcy?

What happens if I were to sue after filing without claiming, and was successful?

Comment: Bankruptcy only affects you up to the time you are granted relief by the court, any debts you incur (like a judgement) after you are relieved in bankruptcy is a new debt. I guess I'm not sure what you are asking, what does suing somebody in the future have to do with a bankruptcy filing?

Comment: @RonBeyer Apologies for not being clearer, I will try to rephrase my question. I am trying to determine if I can sue someone after bankruptcy for something that happened before I filed, or if it even matters.